# How do you effectively use the 'script' command to record an interactive shell?

Tags: command-line

I have been looking at this [reference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/script.1.html) and trying to work out how to actually use the 'script' command. Can someone give me an example usage? All I've been able to do so far is create a blank text file eg `script myChosenFileName`, but it records nothing.

**A bit more info:**

I want to record all the output from my [translations](http://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/) in an interactive shell for future reference. An example command to open this would be `trans -I {de=en}`

*I am sure that this would be an easy question for someone with more CLI experience than me. (I feel a bit silly having the reference right in front of me and still not managing...)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the `script` manpage has no example usage, the related [`scriptreplay` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/scriptreplay.1.html) does have one:

```
% script -t 2> timingfile
Script started, file is typescript
% ls
<etc, etc>
% exit
Script done, file is typescript
% scriptreplay timingfile
```

Essentially, `script` is run once at the beginning of the session, with an optional filename (if none given, the default is called `typescript`). The problem with `script` is that it's an exact copy of everything that happens, so if you try to view the file directly, you will have problems (which is why the `scriptreplay` command is useful - or you could simply `cat` the file).

For your purposes, it might be better, if more verbose, to use a command like `tee`:

```
trans .. | tee some-file
```